# The most used latex symbols

Tags: amsmath, tex-core, tools

I am creating a free offline latex tool for recognizing hand-written latex symbols

https://zaidalyafeai.github.io/texter/

I want to improve the accuracy by knowing what are the most used latex symbols like top 100 for instance. Also, there are lots of repeated symbols so it would be helpful if the list is unique.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Used by *whom*? Used in which sense? Typed or shown in the most-read documents?

Comment: You are probably aware of http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1210/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4485/35864

Comment: @moewe, Texter is cross-platform, does not need an internet connection(no server)  and gives much faster predictions.

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/math/maths-symbols.pdf contains what I would call the more common symbols, while http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf contains 14000 symbols available through various packages.

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive to improve accuracy using the most-used symbols, since they would most likely also be the most well-known and not need such a service.

Comment: I mainly linked the two discussions about detexify and write-math to point you to two people you could try to contact about your project. Maybe the developers of these tools are willing to help you with yours. I was not commenting about the merits of your project. But I see now that you are already using the data set of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4485/35864

Comment: Anyway, I don't think there is a list of top `$n$` TeX symbols. You might be able to write up your own list by scouring the sources of TeX papers available on the arXiv. But an analysis of the source code would have to take into account how TeX and its macros work.

Comment: 100 seems far too few characters, by the time you have upper and lower case latin and greek you are almost up to that before you add any symbols.